# CSS: width of a link doesn't change by setting the width attribute

Tags: css

I have this construction:

```
<a onclick="toggle_media_box(); return false;" href="#" class="media_link">
  <div id="media_link" class="media_link"></div>
</a><br />

#media_link {
  background-image: url("/images/media.png");
}

.media_link {
  width: 445px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Size of the picture is 445px (but was 620px). All other links like this have the size 620px.

In the IE everything works fine and the link is 445px of size. But in Firefox and Chrome the link is still 620px wide. The div has the right size of 445px.

What to do? The `<a>` tag must have the size of 445px.

Interesting thing is, the link does hover up to the size of 445px, but is clickable up to the size of 620px.

Yours Joern.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid to begin with. You cannot have a div inside an anchor. Inline level elements cannot contain block level elements.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Then `<a>` tag is an inline element.  Therefore it's width is determined by the length of the text within the tag.  To fix this you can add `display:block;` to your `.media_link` class and it will perform as expected.

Comment: yeeeehaaaaw! that's it, it started frustrating me. big thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need `float: left` or `display: block` or (ideally) `display: inline-block` on the `a`:

```
.media_link {
    display: inline-block
}
```

---

Your usage of `class="media_link"` twice and `#media_link` is confusing. Using a `<br />` is not required - you can replace that with `display: block`.

I recommend changing to this: http://jsfiddle.net/Yg4YN/2/

```
<a onclick="toggle_media_box(); return false;" href="#" class="media_link">
    <span class="media_span"></span>
</a>

.media_link, .media_span {
    display: block;
    width: 445px;
    height: 200px;
}
.media_span {
    background-image: url("/images/media.png");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML code is currently invalid and you should put the anchor `<a>` inside the `<div>` rather than the other way around.

Once you've got your HTML the right way round, you can set your anchor to `display:block` and size it as required.

Comment: the div is used to display an image which is hoverable

Comment: Do you really need the div? What exactly are you doing with it that you can't do with the anchor?

Comment: it's a link/anchor around a div with background-images for normal and hover.

Comment: If you need a container inside the anchor then i suggest you use a span rather than a div. Currently your HTML is invalid.